# Convert (x,y) coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab, coordinate-transformation

In Matlab I have this matrix:

`Grid` with dimensions `[x,y]`

I've reshaped it to a single row matrix

`Row` with dimensions `[1,x*y]`.

How do i know where to find coordinate `Grid(x,y)` in matrix `Row(1,?)`, and vice versa? Is there a function for this in Matlab?

Comment: @JohanLundberg, you mean their values? They vary, but currently the dimensions are x = 1000 and y = 1000.

Comment: Ok, i have already found how to convert from `Grid` to `Row`: `(y-1) * xWidth + x`. Where xWidth is the total width of `Grid` and x is the coordinate. I still don't know how to convert back though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html) and [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ind2sub.html) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the functions `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` are what you are looking for.  I think.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information as to how you are 'converting the matrix'?

The standard way is to use `B = reshape(A,m,n)` which can be seen in the Matlab documentation for http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html

Reshape:

> returns the m-by-n matrix B whose elements are taken column-wise from
>   A. An error results if A does not have m*n elements.

For example,

```
 a = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


reshape(a,9,1)

     1
     4
     7
     2
     5
     8
     3
     6
     9
```

Thus, one may use sub2ind(matrixSize, rowSub, colSub) 
i.e.

```
sub2ind([3,3], 2, 3)
```

Which as expected, will produce 8

Comment: I used `reshape` like you described.