# MATLAB value extraction

Tags: matlab

I have an image with xi,yi values which I need to extract at certain locations in the image.
For that I've used ginput to get the x,y coordinates of the locations where I need the value.
I then need to extract the value from the image by doing: `value = image(x,y)`.

However:

By asking for the value of the image by saying: `values = image(x(:),y(:));` (coordinates from `ginput`), I get all the possible values of x paired to y, instead of checking the first x-coordinate to the first y-coordinate, and so forth.

Can this be done by a simple MATLAB syntax I haven't thought about, or do I need to construck a loop.. If so, could someone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert (x,y) coordinates in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557840/convert-x-y-coordinates-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `sub2ind`:

```
>> values = image( sub2ind( size(image), y(:), x(:) ) );
```

Note that `x` and `y` are passed as `y`-`x` pairs to `sub2ind`: because matlab addresses entries in matrices in row-column coordinates rather than x-y coordinates.

Comment: @user2782743. Great. welcome to stackoverflow. If you find this answer useful, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "V" icon beside it.